# Can I force my excel workbook to close access DB connections?

Tags: java, excel, ms-access, scheduled-tasks

I have a simple server written in Java that supplies my client apps with data from an access database (.accdb)

The data comes from a query in the database that combines data from multiple worksheets in a linked excel workbook (.xlsx)

This wasn't working out, since the excel workbook needed to be updated regularly by the owner and the database needed constant uptime, and excel locks the file when the database is open.

So to circumvent the problem, I changed the database to run off of a copy of the workbook. I wrote a batch script which kills the java server, thus closing the connection to the database and unlocking the copied excel workbook. It would then copy over the contents of the original to the copied file location, and restart the server, thus updating the data in the database. I set Windows Task Scheduler to run this batch file every day.

Sloppy solution, but it worked. Or so I thought. The batch file only ran once, and hasn't run since then.

So before I go throw another bandaid on this, I figured I'd ask here. Is there a way to setup the original excel workbook to close all connections when a specific user needs to access the file? If I can do that, all I'll have to do is make my server attempt to reconnect after a disconnect, which shouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to think through this and come to a better solution but on my machine I wasn't having any issues like you were describing. Are the server and your clients on different machines? When I update something in the workbooks Access automatically sees it, though they're all open on the same machines. Might be that Access wasn't actually doing anything with the data at the time.

Either way, you might want to think about still using the copy like you are and add this macro under the ThisWorkbook object:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean) 
 ' code to overwrite the databasecopy here
 ' use the Shell() procedure to run system commands to shutdown the database connections
 ' as you need
End Sub
```

This way you still might need to shutdown the server but at least you can do it immediately and only when the workbook is updated.

Also, I've looked around about the actual question you've asked and not found anything exact. You might be able to try something like this:

```
Set ActiveWorkbook.Connections() = Nothing
```

If you can figure out the index of the connection. Or perhaps iterate over all of them and then start them back up after. Don't have anymore time to try and figure out if this solution works at the moment. Hopefully it gets you on the right foot.

Comment: Yea, they're all on different machines. The excel workbook (source) exists on a shared network drive, the server runs on a drive connected to the network, and the clients are separate machines which cannot be connected to the network (due to policy, not technical limitations)
---
Your experience sums up what's I originally wanted to happen. The access DB (which is always being accessed by the java server, which is always communicating with the clients) gets real-time data from the excel file, which for some reason doesn't let anyone edit the file. I'll mess around with what you suggested.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this, but I assume the files get locked when opened on one machine(where the server is running) so they files aren't able to be opened in another instance on the client machines. If they did, you might run into versioning issues if someone saves while another is opened. This is what happens to me with an Access file on a network drive. Depending on how real-time you need the data you might want to just think about opening the Excel file, updating your database and closing it again, having the server run that periodically. Don't know if that solves anything.